# Highchart bubblechart custom symbol

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to get the bubblechart in highcharts to draw with a custom symbol (such as square, triangle, etc etc). This works wonderfully for scatter but bubble doesn't seem to cooperate when you switch type to bubble.
Here's the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var bubbleOne = {
        x:20,
        y:10, 
        z: 15,
        marker:{
            symbol: "square"
        },
    };
    var bubbleTwo = {
        x:10,
        y:20, 
        z:10,
        marker:{
            symbol: "triangle"
        },
    };
    $(function() {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart : {
                type : 'bubble'
            },
            series : [{
                data : [bubbleOne, bubbleTwo]
            }]

        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this option is not available in bubble chart, only in scatter type. But you can request your suggestion in our uservoice system: http://highcharts.uservoice.com/

Comment: Has this been implemented? This is a make or break deal for me to use highcharts.

Comment: Unfortuantely its still not implemented. http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/3913511-allow-for-custom-symbols-when-using-bubble-chart

Comment: The scatter chart works perfect though. Took me a while to realize that!